How to figure out if it is dangerous to light Chanuka candles outside
According to Halacha (see Yalkut Yosef 671), one shouldn't light the Chanuka candles outside one's home if it is dangerous. Given that there is an opinion that it is obligatory to light them outside if it is not dangerous (and I want to ignore the opinion that it's not permitted to ever light outside for the sake of this question), what is considered "dangerous" for these purposes?
Clearly, we don't live in times as dangerous as Turyanos, but then again, it's still considered dangerous (especially since Oct 7th)

On an unsourced, logical basis, it’s probably not a good idea unless one lives in a predominantly-Jewish area and is able to cover the candles with one of those transparent cubes. Otherwise, there’s a fire risk from wind and/or anti-Semites

I don't see how this is objectively answerable. Personally I don't think it's dangerous basically anywhere "normal" in the USA. Can't speak to Europe but it's probably fine most places too. These things aren't quantifiable. How do you determine when it's sufficiently dangerous to post a guard outside a shul on Shabbat? When to allow washing hands from potential germs on Yom Kippur (came up during Covid)? Etc.

@Qwertl glass boxes didn't exist 2000 years ago. Unless you have very unusual weather concerns, that's not a reason to avoid buying stable lamps for this purpose like everyone used to do. One trick is to put the menorah in a bucket of water so it is very bottom heavy and if somehow it tips the water tips too. Though anyway now anyone can get a fancy glass cube for $30 bucks delivered to your door in 2 days.

@DoubleAA I totally agree with you on this. Nonetheless, there are halachot about it and if the answer is "it's up to each person to determine for themselves" or "it's up to the Rabbi to determine for his community", then that's fine, but I imagine there will be some "case law" on this to draw precedent from. Leaving people to decide without any guidelines beyond the word "danger" isn't really ideal

@RabbiK I doubt there's any case law because communities generally either always do it or always don't do it without any regard for the sugya. I've never heard of a community ever that would change where it lights annually based on that years evaluation. Maybe you'll find someone in the last 50 years who had a weird Israeli army case or something and made something up.

Notably, one also shouldn't light Chanukah candles inside his home if it is dangerous. How does one determine that?

@DoubleAA in this case, I am also having trouble understanding you. Could you directly state your point? I am not figuring it out from your questioning. Either way, the halacha of not lighting inside if it is dangerous is different in many substantial ways to the halacha of not lighting outside due to the events surrounding Turyanos, and how these events have produced discussions that have made it to the pages of the halachic codeces themselves. There are Rabbis who have to make this decision at times. If you are convinced the answer is "they should make something up", please source and answer

@RabbiKaii There is no way to objectively measure danger for inside lighting either. How much fire risk is too much? There's always more than 0% and less than 100% chance. Everyone has to make a good judgement. There's no reason to think this is any different.

Always more than 0% and less than 100% is presented as a hurdle that cannot be dealt with by logic, but that's not the case. I consider Issur V'Heter to be a great example of this, but nevermind.

@RabbiKaii See Rav Schachter's t'shuva (Piskei Corona, 48) regarding washing on Tisha B'av in the case of a small (but not precisely determined) risk of danger that is subjectively evaluated differently by each individual.

Rav Moshe Sternbach (Moadim uzmanim) in his conclusion (to explain the minhag in various places to light inside) explained that "shas sakana - a dangerous time" just means we're afraid a non jew will extinguish the light (which will diminish the pirsumei nisa). I understand from that that any place with non jews in the street suffices.

I've been to many places with non-jews in the streets where I was not afraid they'd come extinguish candles that are on my property. Something doesn't add up.

Curious how Rabbi Shternbuch felt in his native South Africa.

@Shalom He's a Londoner

@DoubleAA ah, sorry. Though I'd heard he was influenced by his time as a posek in Johannesburg ... a lot of beggars-can't-be-choosers situations.
